# How to display the attribute table of the map using Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo, web-gis

I'm developing a Leaflet application. For that I want to display the complete attribute table of a particular WMS layer using Leaflet.

Is it possible that we can do that?

Answer (score 1):

That's possible using a plugin for leaflet. Take a look on this one 
https://github.com/heigeo/leaflet.wms

You'll be able to display a popup containing attributes for each feature of a wms layer, thanks to the GetFeatureInfo

Comment: Yeah.that's correct but i want to see the full attribute table of the wms layer not for particular feature.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to get **ALL** the attributes for a WMS layer, it doesn't matter whether you are using Leaflet or not.

If you want all the attribute information from the underlying data, you will need to retrieve the data itself, so you will need that the WMS service provider also provides an accompanying WFS or WCS service.